# Can I contact my computer manufacturer for getting a new copy of my OS?

Tags: windows-vista, hp-pavilion

About a year ago, my windows Vista computer's hard drive failed and I put it in the closet and forgot about it. Now I have someone who would like to use it, but obviously needs a new hard drive and new OS. This is a HP Pavilion Slimline s3500f PC. It's over eight years old and was store-bought.

Do I have to buy a new copy of Vista or is there a way to contact HP to get one from them? I still have the serial number on the sticker on the computer. I also tried to go to the recovery site on microsoft.com without any luck.

I'm not very adept at asking thorough questions. If you need any more information please comment and I will update it promptly.

Comment: Usually with companies like HP, you can call them and order new OS disks (not at full price - they usually charge around $10-15 for the disks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the serial number you should not need to purchase a new copy of Vista.

Have a look at http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Recovery/Windows-Vista-7-and-8-ISO-Image-file-Download-Links/td-p/2954293 - I'd imagine one of these downloads will be fine - otherwise hunt arround a bit for "Vista" "HP" and "Digital River" - Digital River are the official Microsoft channel for destributing ISO's so you should be OK downloading one from them.

Depending on what happens you might have to go through "Phone Activation" when installing your system, but other then a hassle that shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the boot.wim was removed from whatever site it was hosted on from the link you posted. But your answer should get me going in the right direction. Thank you for the help.